# Joining dataframes by referencing a third master dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Suppose I had a dataframe of dataframe names and join keys that served as a master table for how to join my dataframes.  How would I go about joining these dataframes by referencing this master dataframe? Assume that dataframes 1 and 2 are already objects in my environment.

dataframe of dataframes

| col1 | col2 | Join_Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| df1 | df2 | join_key_value |

If I do

```
pd.merge(col1.df1,col2.df2,on = Join_Key.join_key_value)
```

this won't work because this would reference the literal value "df1".  I want to reference the table that "df1" refers to.

Answer (score 1):

`df.loc[0, 'col1']` gives the name string of the DataFrame 'df1' where df is your 'master' DataFrame and so on (assuming there is just one row index 0 - otherwise select the row).
Then assuming that df1 is in the global NameSpace (ie not a Local) then you can access the actual DataFrame using:

```
my_df1 = globals()[df.loc[0, 'col1']]
```

The various DataFrames can be so accessed and merged as is required.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  If it did, wouldn't df.loc[0,'col1'].columns return the column names? 
Instead I get the following:  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: My mistake. I assumed you had a DataFrame of DataFrames (which can be useful) rather than of DataFrame **names**.  Code now edited to extract and make use of the name.

Comment: Thanks - what if I had more than one row and needed to do multiple merges?

Comment: Just access each DF in the same way using the row and column of the 'master' DF where the names are to be found and then merge as required, for example `my_df2 = globals()[df.loc[0, 'col2']]`  where 0 is the row index and 'col2' the column to access the name or whatever suits the position in the master DF. This works because `global()` accesses global objects using their names as strings,